# How to get pixel color from a Pixmap

Tags: x11, pixmap

I can use `XGetPixel()` to get a pixel from an `XImage`. What do I use to get a pixel from a `Pixmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be nice if there was at least one function to pull a pixel from the server's drawable. Sadly, there isn't one. However the following might be of some use.

Since `Pixmap` is a `Drawable` you can pass `XGetImage()` the `Pixmap` which will return a pointer to an `XImage`. Now that you have an `XImage` you can use `XGetPixel()`.

#### XGetImage Parameters:

```
XImage *XGetImage(display, d, x, y, width, height, plane_mask, format)
        Display *display;
        Drawable d;
        int x, y;
        unsigned int width, height;
        unsigned long plane_mask;
        int format;
```

Better yet you could have a pre-created `XImage` and pass it, along with the `Pixmap` to `XGetSubImage()`. You can grab a single pixel by passing a width and height both set to 1, and then use `XGetPixel()` on your `XImage`.

#### XGetSubImage Parameters:

```
XImage *XGetSubImage(display, d, x, y, width, height, plane_mask, format, dest_image, dest_x, 
                     dest_y)
      Display *display;
      Drawable d;
      int x, y;
      unsigned int width, height;
      unsigned long plane_mask;
      int format;
      XImage *dest_image;
      int dest_x, dest_y;
```

**Note**: `XGetSubImage()` returns a pointer to the same `XImage` structure specified by `dest_image`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's a bad idea from performance point of view: never read from screen, only push to it. If you need to get pixel state, maintain local buffer of screen. If you can't modify program you are using, then +1 to Jonny Henly's answer: do a GetImage request first do download a region containing your pixel first, then read locally. If you want to access multiple pixels in a loop it's better to grab them all in one request

Comment: My program is reading from the root window (the desktop) at the current pointer's position and displaying it, modified, in a window. So I think I have no choice but to "read from screen", right?

Comment: yeah, probably no choice